# GCP - Minimum permissions required to start/stop Compute Engine Instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've set up a GCP project, with a few Compute Engine VM Instances that will be used off and on at different times of the day.

So that I don't have to stay glued to the console all the time, what is the minimum/least amount of permissions I can grant to a user, so they can start/stop the instances as needed?

They would also need to download the RDP file (these are Windows instances).

From what I can tell, I need:

- compute.instances.start
- compute.instances.stop
- compute.instances.reset

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They would at least need the roles/compute.admin permission to be able to accomplish the tasks mentioned above. You can also read more about Compute Engine IAM roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute_admin_role). The link attached will provide further information in regards to Compute Engine IAM roles.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I see that I can create a custom role that has these specific permissions. Does that sound right?

Comment: That is correct. If you do not want to use the predefined roles, then you can create a custom role using a combination of different permissions to meet your needs.